# Reg for letters, numbers, commas

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a regex builder, where you tell it what you choose to whitelist/blacklist and the builder spits out the regex?  I've been reading about regex all day and still not getting specs to pass.

How would I create a regex to allow the following?

```
  "RDM, S21, 021, E37, eeges"
```

What I have so far (that doesn't work) is

```
  /\A[a-zA-Z0-9,]\z/
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks @hwnd. Specs passed. Regex blows my mind. Add an answer and I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow whitespace and precede the character class with a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
\A[a-zA-Z0-9\s,]+\z
```